# Javascript array and information retrieve

Tags: javascript, xml, arrays, math, shuffle

Ok so I'm not even sure how to title this post but I have a little logical problem that I need help with. So on a front page of a website I need 4 boxes. These four boxes contain 1 image, 1 title, one date. The trick is, these four boxes need to be randomly generated from a list of 10. So in javascript is it possible to create something like an xml structure to pick 4 random from then populate... so the way I want it to work is...

- Item 1

  - date
  - title
  - src
- Item 2

  - date
  - title
  - src
- Item 3

  - date
  - title
  - src

Is it possible to put the items in an array then access the properties of them after they are randomly selected? I could do this with PHP/MySQL but that's very unnecessary for this. any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: How about storing the items in objects using JSON?

Comment: any examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, yes. Long answer below.

```
var obj1 = {
    date: "04/12/1989",
    title: "My birthday",
    src: "path_to_some_image.png"
}
var obj2 = {
    date: "12/25/2011",
    title: "Christmas",
    src: "santa_claus.gif"
}

objs = [obj1, obj2];
rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * objs.length);

console.log(objs[rand].title + " is " + objs[rand].date);
// "My birthday is 04/12/1989"
// or "Christmas is 12/25/2011"
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use `Math.random` for this purpose. Put your list in an Array, then pick a random number between 0 and 9 and choose that item. You'd do this four times and you're good to go... **unless** you don't want the same item twice (or more often) - which I am pretty sure is what you want. No repetition, I mean. That makes things more interesting, if you don't want a [biased](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias) probability distribution. In that case, the algorithm goes like this:

1. i = Random number between 0 and 9 -> pick array[i]
2. if (i == 9) -> all is well, skip 3
3. if (i<9) -> swap array[i] and array[9]
4. j = Random number between 0 and 8 -> pick array[j]
5. if (j == 8) -> all well, skip 6
6. if (j < 8) -> swap array[j] and array[8]
7. k = Random number between 0 and 7 -> pick array[k]
   ...

You get the pattern.The method is also known as the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score 1):

You should use an array of objects..

```
var items = [{
    'date': 'date of item 1',
    'title': 'title of item 1',
    'src': 'url/of/image-1'},
{
    'date': 'date of item 2',
    'title': 'title of item 2',
    'src': 'url/of/image-2'},
/* .. more items.. */
{
    'date': 'date of item 9',
    'title': 'title of item 9',
    'src': 'url/of/image-9'},
{
    'date': 'date of item 10',
    'title': 'title of item 10',
    'src': 'url/of/image-10'}];

for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    var item = items.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * (items.length)), 1)[0];

    var el = document.getElementById('item-' + i);
    // insert the info you want in the DOM .. i just add it as text..
    el.innerHTML= item.date + ' - ' + item.title + ' - ' + item.src;
}
```

And use a pre-defined html

```
<div id="item-1"></div>
<div id="item-2"></div>
<div id="item-3"></div>
<div id="item-4"></div>
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/qkMNb/1/